# Do I have to pay duty or taxes on bags of coffee as I transit the USA and enter the UK?

Tags: usa, uk, customs-and-immigration, import-taxes, food-and-drink

My question is perhaps unusual, but I want to make sure I won't have any problems.

Can I travel with three bags of coffee, each 250 grams for personal use. I have a layover in the US before my onward flight to the UK.

Would I have to pay duty or taxes, e.g., excise or VAT?

Comment: As it is a food product, you'll have to declare it when you enter the USA.  There shouldn't be any tax or duty though.  Not sure about the UK.

Comment: Where are you travelling from? And where is the coffee from?

Comment: If it's commercially packaged it should be fine. Remember that you have to declare it in the UK and in the US if you bring it through US customs.

Comment: If you prefer a specific brand, then fine, but it's easy to buy good-quality coffee in the UK.

Answer (score 2):

[DEFRA](http://importdetails.defra.gov.uk/Default.aspx?Location=None&Module=IDDSearch) specifies for the UK what is and is not allowed in terms of food products. Coffee does not feature so you may assume it is permitted (and even were it not the worst that could happen is that it is confiscated).

No tax or duty is payable for goods imported personally for own consumption or as a gift [provided](https://www.gov.uk/duty-free-goods/arrivals-from-outside-the-eu):

> You can bring in other goods worth up to £390 (or up to £270 if you arrive by private plane or boat).
>
> If a single item’s worth more than your allowance you pay any duty or tax on its full value, not just the value above the allowance.

Answer (score -1):

Well the coffee is from Colombia and I'm flying from there and yes is is a commercially packed as well. I will declare it of course, as I don't want to hide anything from the officials and I think, as most of you here that everything should be fine. t